# Export GDB to CAD

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, autocad

How may export multiple shapefile in GDB to cad? after export l want to get same count cad file as in GDB. 
l have used export to cad, but merged all shapefile in one cad file.

Comment: Have you tried Conversion Tools, To Cad, Export to Cad? You can append an existing cad file, if need be.

Comment: Yes. but merged all and created one.

Comment: You want to export multiple layers in a gdb to their own cad file? If you right-click Export_to_Cad, there is a batch option. Not sure what you are trying to accomplish.